# NGINX: Replace random query values with static values

Tags: nginx, replace, query-string, request-uri

I know that my question had been answered once already, but it seams that I can't find it anymore. My apologies for that :)

Is there a way I can replace non alphanumeric characters returned with $request_uri with a a static value?
My URL looks like this:

mydomaine.com/videos/1122/master.m3u8?Device-ID=123456&Session-ID=7890123&**api_key=5bc06b7a6**&Codec=h264&AudioCodec=mp3

api_key=5bc06b7a6 is a random non alphanumeric value and changes each time the URL is requested.

How can I replace this value for api_key with a static value? e.g. api_key=abc123def456

Comment: Its actually seen by the backend only. I have tried:  if ($args ~* "(.*)(api_key=([^a-z0-9\+]))(.*)) {
set $args "$1api_key=123abc456def";}

Comment: What's the backend? `fastcgi_pass`, `proxy_pass`, `uwsgi_pass`? Can you show the `location` block that ultimately handles the request?

Comment: It is location..

location /web/item/ {
### Replacement code###
}